# Estimating volume of a simple object

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, diophantine-approximation

Volume computation is $\#P$ hard.

Take the $[0,1]^n$ polytope.

Slice it by an half space inequality with $poly(n)$ bit rational coefficients into two unequal halves.

Volume of bigger section is $\frac12+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon\in(0,\frac12)$ holds.

> 1. Is there an efficient polynomial time deterministic algorithm to find $\frac pq$ where each integer $p$ and $q$ are of $poly(n)$ bits so that we can achieve $|\frac pq-\epsilon|<\frac1{poly(n)}$?
> 2. Related Diophantine problem is if each integer $p$ and $q$ are of $poly(n)$ bits then what is the smallest $$|\frac pq-\epsilon|$$ we can achieve regardless of being bound in polynomial time when the half space inequality has $poly(n)$ bit rational coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quasi-done in.

*Marichal, Jean-Luc; Mossinghoff, Michael J.*, [**Slices, slabs, and sections of the unit hypercube**](http://web.math.rochester.edu/misc/ojac/vol3/Marichal_2008.pdf), Online J. Anal. Comb. 3, Article 1, 11 p. (2008). [ZBL1189.52011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1189.52011).

Comment: Seems like closed formula exists however good enough for polynomial time?

Comment: @Turbo Looks like it to me - some of products.

Comment: Which products are in polynomial time?

Comment: Isn't the relevant formula (3)? It's not clear to me why the sum can be computed in polynomial time, although maybe I am missing a trick.